# 8.51 tools PSAPPSRV crash

Tags: crash, peoplesoft

Tried to install fresh instance of PT on VM running Linux with following versions:
OS: Linux CentOS 6.5 64bit
Database: Oracle 11.2.0.1 64bit
App Serv: Tuxedo 11gR1 11.1.1.3 64bit RP015
Web Serv: WebLogic 10.3.6
JDK: Jrockit for linux jdk 1.6.0_45 R28.2.7-4.1.0 64bit
PT: 8.51.25

I could:
- start DB, able to connect w SQLPLUS, App Designer, Data Mover
- start App Serv (listening on ports 7000, 9000)
- start Web Serv
- Access to Web Page (Web Serv is running fine)

Once I load PIA login page, I got TPESVCERR error (default setting error).
Same error if i try to login via PIA.

> > > Web Serv Log (same error can be seen repeatedly)

```
SEVERE  psft.pt8.net.NetReqRepSvc   sendRequest TPESVCERR - server error while handling request
SEVERE  psft.pt8.net.NetReqRepSvc   sendRequest An error occurred on the application server within Jolt while running the service.  Cancel the current operation and retry.  If the problem persists contact your system administrator. Error Code:10
SEVERE  psft.pt8.net.NetReqRepSvc   sendRequest Application Server last connected //192.168.236.129_9000
SEVERE  psft.pt8.auth.WebProfile    loadProfile ERROR: WebProfile loading internal default settings because of an Exception while communicating with "192.168.236.129:9000"
SEVERE  psft.pt8.auth.WebProfile    loadProfile TPESVCERR - server error while handling request
SEVERE  psft.pt8.net.NetReqRepSvc   sendRequest TPESVCERR - server error while handling request
SEVERE  psft.pt8.net.NetReqRepSvc   sendRequest An error occurred on the application server within Jolt while running the service.  Cancel the current operation and retry.  If the problem persists contact your system administrator. Error Code:10
SEVERE  psft.pt8.net.NetReqRepSvc   sendRequest Application Server last connected //192.168.236.129_9000
SEVERE  psft.pt8.util.PIAPerfUtil   initializePSPerf    PerfMon: Unable to retrieve performance monitor MonitorURL, Reason:Error connecting to AppServer, Ppm JoltSession to 192.168.236.129:9000 not created, reason: bea.jolt.ServiceException: TPESVCERR - server error while handling request
```

> > > App Serv Log (same error can be seen repeatedly)

```
PSAPPSRV.3767 (1) [06/25/14 09:29:08 GetCertificate](0) Process aborted.
PSPAL: Abort: Unexpected signal received
PSPAL: Abort: Location: /vob/peopletools/src/pspal/exception_sigaction.cpp:494: RecoverableSignalHandler
PSPAL: Abort: Generating process state report to /db/pt851cfg/appserv/psdb1/LOGS/PSAPPSRV.3983/process_state.txt
PSAPPSRV.4171 (0) [06/25/14 09:29:15](0) PeopleTools Release 8.51.25 (Linux) starting. Tuxedo server is APPSRV(99)/1
PSAPPSRV.4171 (0) [06/25/14 09:29:15](0) Cache Directory being used: /db/pt851cfg/appserv/psdb1/CACHE/PSAPPSRV_1/
PSAPPSRV.4171 (0) [06/25/14 09:29:15](2) App server host time skew is DB+00:00:00 (ORACLE PSDB)
PSAPPSRV.4171 (0) [06/25/14 09:29:15](2) (PreloadMemoryCache) No project name set in the configuration file Cache Settings parameter, PreloadMemoryCache.  Nothing to preload into memory cache.
PSAPPSRV.4171 (0) [06/25/14 09:29:15](2) Use FTP Library has value : Y
PSAPPSRV.4171 (0) [06/25/14 09:29:15](0) Server started
PSAPPSRV.3983 (1) [06/25/14 09:29:17 GetCertificate](0) Process aborted.
```

> > > Tuxedo Log (same error can be seen repeatedly)

```
092925.PSDB!PSAPPSRV.4357.735041312.0: 06-25-2014: Tuxedo Version 11.1.1.3.0, 64-bit
092925.PSDB!PSAPPSRV.4357.735041312.0: LIBTUX_CAT:262: INFO: Standard main starting
092925.PSDB!PSAPPSRV.4357.735041312.0: LIBTUX_CAT:476: WARN: Server 99/2: client process 3487: lost message
092925.PSDB!PSAPPSRV.4357.735041312.0: LIBTUX_CAT:477: WARN: SERVICE=GetCertificate    MSG_ID=0    REASON=server died
```

I don't think there is any problem with connection between Web Serv and App Serv.
(When i shutdown App Serv, Web Serv will complain of App Serv not available)
From the logs, it appears that PSAPPSRV crashed while working on GetCertificate request.
The debug info says "unable to determine location of exception" which is troubling.
Extract from stack trace:

```
#0  0x0000003b80ae15e3 in select () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f3ccafc58f7 in PSPAL::DumpProcessState::CallDebugger(int, char const*, PSPAL::ExceptionContext const*, bool) () from /db/pt851/bin/libpspal64.so
#2  0x00007f3ccafc5bd4 in PSPAL::DumpProcessState::GenerateAbortDiagnostics(char const*, PSPAL::ExceptionContext*) () from /db/pt851/bin/libpspal64.so
#3  0x00007f3ccafba1db in PSPAL::Abort(char const*, char const*, int, char const*, PSPAL::ExceptionContext*) () from /db/pt851/bin/libpspal64.so
#4  0x00007f3ccafbfad1 in PSPAL::SigactionSignalHandler::RecoverableSignalHandler(int, siginfo*, void*) () from /db/pt851/bin/libpspal64.so
#5  0x00007f3ccafc03a5 in PSPAL::SigactionSignalHandler::SignalHandler(int, siginfo*, void*) () from /db/pt851/bin/libpspal64.so
#6  <signal handler called>
#7  0x00007f3cca099f0e in CReadSerialObj::Init(void*) () from /db/pt851/bin/libpscmnutils.so
#8  0x00007f3cca09a275 in CReadSerialObj::CReadSerialObj(EOBJECT_TYPE, void*) () from /db/pt851/bin/libpscmnutils.so
#9  0x00007f3cca09a449 in CReadFrame::CReadFrame(EOBJECT_TYPE, void*) () from /db/pt851/bin/libpscmnutils.so
#10 0x00007f3cc8b33b59 in CNetRecvMsg::CNetRecvMsg(void*) () from /db/pt851/bin/libpsnetapi.so
#11 0x00007f3cc8b3e557 in CNetReqRepSvc::CNetReqRepSvc(CNetServer*, tpsvcinfo*, wchar_t const*) () from /db/pt851/bin/libpsnetapi.so
#12 0x00007f3cc082ce5c in CCertificateService::CCertificateService(CNetServer*, IPSSignonPeopleCode*, tpsvcinfo*) () from /db/pt851/bin/libpssecurity.so
#13 0x00007f3cc082f2a7 in CertificateServiceFactory::Create(CNetServer*, IPSSignonPeopleCode*, tpsvcinfo*) const () from /db/pt851/bin/libpssecurity.so
#14 0x0000000000419235 in CAppServer::GetCertificate(tpsvcinfo*) ()
#15 0x000000000041549d in GetCertificate ()
#16 0x00007f3cccdaca4b in _tmsvcdsp () from /db/tuxedo/tuxedo11gR1/lib/libtux.so
#17 0x00007f3cccdd4146 in _tmrunserver () from /db/tuxedo/tuxedo11gR1/lib/libtux.so
#18 0x00007f3cccdaa42c in _tmstartserver () from /db/tuxedo/tuxedo11gR1/lib/libtux.so
#19 0x000000000040a747 in main ()
```

Have tried many different configuration settings, no joy. Could it be library compatibility issue? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE: I uninstalled tuxedo 11gR1 and install tuxedo 10gR3 w RP141. No more error and the PIA works. It looks like PT8.51 does not like tuxedo 11gR1. Not sure about windows or solaris, at least for linux.
Case close.

Answer (score 1):

8:51 PT version is only certified for Oracle Tuxedo version 10.3.0.0.0

And you are using version 11g, this may be the problem of crash AppServer.

hope this helps :)